# Method Not Allowed REST Java when trying to do POST

Tags: java, rest, http-status-code-405

I just want to create a simple REST service and it uses `@GET` and `@POST`.
for the `@GET` function, everything is ok but for `@POST`, when I want to create a new user on my server the browser just keeps sating (METHOD NOT ALLOWED).
I read so many articles about how to fix this error but I haven't got anything yet.

My code for `@POST` :

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloResource(){
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/post")
public Response createUser(@PathParam("name") String name,@PathParam("address") String address,@PathParam("birthYear") String birth,@PathParam("ps") String password) throws NotAllowedException,MethodNotFoundException,Exception {


    DataStore.getInstance().putPerson(new Person(name, address, Integer.parseInt(birth), password));
    String json = "{\n";
    json += "\"status\": " + '"'+"CREATED" +'"'+ ",\n";
    json+="}";
    return Response.status(200).entity(json).build();





}}
```

I also tried adding `@Consumes` function with (MediaType.APPLICATION.JSON) and (MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) but nothing changed.

Also the URL I enter for posting is :

```
http://localhost:8080/HelloREST/rest/hello/post?name=PouYad&address=mustbejsonlater&birthYear=2005&ps=12345
```

As you see I also tried so many exception handlers.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Are you actually sending a POST request? Try adding a @GET handler. I'm guessing that you're actually sending a GET request to your application; "Method not allowed" would be the expected error in that case, since you only have a handler for POST.

Comment: You're using the wrong annotation. Use `@QueryParam`, not `@PathParam`, for those.

Comment: @GabrielBauman. What do you mean

Comment: Can you try with Postman tool ? set http method as post and try.

Comment: @PooyaSalehi I mean that you are probably sending a GET request to your endpoint instead of a POST. The error is telling you exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. if you enter your URL in the browser URL address field, it won't work because the browser will send a "GET" request. So you must use a client that will allow you to send a "POST" like PostMan. Or write your own small httpConnection function that sends a "POST"
2. You also have to change the @PathParam to @FormParam for it to work (@QueryParam will also work, but because it is POST, it is best to use @FormParm).

Answer (score 1):

Access URL directly through browser can only create Get Request, not POST Request

You should

1. Create HTML Form, set the action to your service url with POST method, and then submit it.
2. Use Rest Client like postman to access your service with POST method.
3. Write your own Http Client using java.net.http api or just simply use 
   one of the handy libraries/frameworks (Like Spring has RestTemplate).